# Bash string substitution for sed argument: Sed: unknown command: `''

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to make a function in .bashrc to run this command:

```
lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/VGA/,/^$/ p'
```

, where `VGA` would be substituted with the first argument `$1`.

This is what I came up with:

```
lsp(){
    sed_str="'/$1/,/^$/ p'"
    echo $sed_str
    lspci -kvnn | sed -n $sed_str
    return
}
export -f lsp
```

I cannot understand why the function fails, the `echo $sed_str` (there for troubleshooting) output looks exactly the same as the regex in the first command. **Still sed is complaining:**

```
[user@linux ~]$ lsp VGA
'/VGA/,/^$/ p'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
[user@linux ~]$
```

There's probably something obvious I'm not seeing here.

Kernel and shell:

```
uname -r      -> 5.8.14-arch1-1
echo $SHELL   -> /bin/bash
```

Comment: Welcome to SE, Raflemakt ! When an answer is provided to you and you are satisfied with it, you can formally ***accept*** it, and also upvote it.  To accept it please select the greyed check mark located left below the upvote score. This way others will instantly recognize that your question has a valid answer. Incidentally the answerer will also get rewarded with karma points.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about accepting an answer (which is hard when you have two helpful answers). I did upvote them, though. However it seems upvotes from new accounts with less than 15 reputation aren't showed publicly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes within your string, not just delimiting your string. You need to use quotes to define your string as well as use it:

```
lsp(){
    sed_str="/$1/,/^$/ p"
    echo $sed_str
    lspci -kvnn | sed -n "$sed_str"
    return
}
export -f lsp
```

Comment: This did indeed solve the issue, thanks a lot!"

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sed_str="/$1/,/^\$/p"

>>>> lspci -kvnn | sed -n "$sed_str"
```

The single quotes are the source of trouble. Also you need to double quote the
`$sed_str`   variable to protect it from word splitting nd file name expansion after it has been expanded.

Since you did not quote your variables so it appears as following to the shell

```
 ... ¦ sed -n '/VGA/,/^$/ 'p

arg1 =   -n
arg2 =  '/VGA/,/^$/
arg3  = 'p
```

see 2 and 3 don't make sense to sed and it is complaining for that. It thinks `'`  is some sed command.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, removing the extra single quotes and putting quotes around `$sed_str` solved the issue, as B.Morris also pointed out.